# How to detect the timezone of a client?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, timezone

How to get client/request timezone in jsp?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Unfortunately this information is not passed in HTTP headers.

Usually you need cooperating JavaScript to fetch it for you.
Web is full of examples, here is one http://www.coderanch.com/t/486127/JSP/java/Query-timezone

Answer (score 1):

you cannot get timezone, but you can get current time from client side.i.e. through javascript and than post back. On server side, you can convert that time to GMT/UTC. The UTC shows the TimeZone.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the local timezone in order to display local times to the user, I recommend representing all times in your service in UTC and rendering them in browsers as local times using [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com).

My general rule is to handle and store times in UTC everywhere except at the interface with the user, where you convert to/from local time. The advantage of UTC is that you never have to worry about daylight-saving adjustments.

Note that if you want to show the age of something (e.g. "posted 3 hours ago") you just need to compare the UTC timestamp with the current UTC time; no need to convert to local times at all.

Comment: I have a requirement, where I have to download data in pdf. So need to show date in user's timezone in the pdf. How do I do that.