# How to get local date-time and not server date-time

Tags: java, jsp, date, time, weblogic

I am making a Java web application in whcih customers in different countries are required to upload file through a jsp page.I have to deploy this application in Weblogic server.

Now what i want is their local date-time.I dont want server date-time.

What code should I write in my java application to get their local date and time.

Comment: HTTP POST will not contain that info, I think... Your only option would be to grab the IP of the client socket, do a geoip lookup on it and determine the timezone according to geoip results...

Comment: Or use JavaScript to read the local time in the browser and then submit it to the server. Or use relative times such as "2 hours ago".

Comment: Similar: [*How to detect the timezone of a client?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3001260/642706)

Answer (score 4):

It's tough to get time of user/client unless you pass it explicitly in the post/Ajax call.

Capture time in Javascript and then send it to server in http request.

URL : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at this question: [Determining a web user's time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/determining-a-web-users-time-zone). Please see the answer of "JD Isaacks" with a lot of upvotes.

Than you can pass the timezone "offset" to your Java application through an ajax call and use it to calculate the users local date and time.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get the clients timestamp is to retrieve it on the client and send it to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Using JavaScript() use Date() function and you can send it to server using ajax. You can call this javascript and ajax function right during bodyLoad().

Comment: Can you elborate more on that.How do I capture then information send thru ajax on the otherside

Answer (score 0):

Use following JQuery ajax call function.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ServletTest",
        data: "clientdate=" + new Date()
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script>
    var d = new Date();
    alert(d);
</script>
```