# Is it possible to convert datetime fields from UTC to client's local time with django rest framework

Tags: javascript, python, django, datetime

This is my article model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source)
    datetime_ingested = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    image_src = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
```

And this is my serializer:

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'headline', 'source', 'datetime_ingested', 'content', 'image_src')
```

All date time fields are in UTC, and I want to convert the time to the client's localtime. Is this possible to do from the framework's side? Right now I'm serving the content, parsing the date using `moment.js` (https://momentjs.com/) to display contextual datetime based on the current timezone like so:

```
moment(article['datetime_ingested'], "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss").fromNow()
```

But this translates UTC to now. Is it possible to tell Django to serve the datetime fields in the client's timezone?

The datetime string looks like so:

```
2017-01-26T03:49:34.232000Z
```

Comment: When parsing a date string, you should **always** provide the format. What does `article['datetime_ingested']` look like?

Comment: @RobG looks like this: 2017-01-26T03:49:34.232000Z, I believe Z is UTC.

Comment: http header does not include client locale... so you have to JS to get the timezone, and keep the timezone in session/cookie... you can have a look of this post...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001260/how-to-detect-client-timezone